# Printing the elements of an unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11

So I am writing a small code to remove the duplicate characters from a string. I have done it using map, vector but wanted to use unordered_set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char* str = "abbcdeffg";
    std::unordered_set<char> ump;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str) ; i++)
    {
        ump.insert(str[i]);
    }

    for (auto it = ump.begin(); it != ump.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the elements are being printed in the reverse order of their insertion. The output is gfedcba. Please can someone explain why?

And what would be the best way to print the elements in the original order. There is no operator--() in unordered_set as it has got forward iterator.

Thanks!

Comment: It's because it is "**unordered**"

Comment: You might want to pull that `strlen()` out of the loop.

Comment: And stop initialising `char*` from string literals. That hasn't been allowed for _years_. Turn on your warnings!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

**You cannot.**

An unordered set does not have any inherent ordering.

That's why it's called an *unordered* set.

A `vector` (or, better yet, a `deque`) would be the appropriate output container here, but you could possibly make use an additional, *temporary*, `set`, to keep track of duplicates whilst you iterate.